# Circular Structure to JSON, UI Runtime Error TypeError

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am getting an error when trying to parse and stringify some JSON data.

On this line:

```
this.copyOfColumns = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.assign([], this.columns)));
```

Here is the entire @Input (using Angular 4):

```
  @Input()
  set gridColumns(gridColumnsArr: Array<object>) {
    console.log('gridColumnsArr');
    console.log(gridColumnsArr);
    this.columns = this.sortActiveAndInactiveColumns(gridColumnsArr);
    console.log('this.columns');
    console.log(this.columns);
    this.copyOfColumns = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.assign([], this.columns)));
    console.log('this.copyOfColumns');
    console.log(this.copyOfColumns);
  }
```

Here is the data logged to the console (this.columns)...and the error(s) following:

[image]

Comment: why did you not set this.copyOfColumns = JSON.stringify(Object.assign([], this.columns));

Comment: Tried that, get the exact same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to deep copy the array by using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`. Apparently your data structure has [circular references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value) which fails the `JSON.stringify()`.

Either you should sanitize your data to not contain ciruclar references or you could try using a library like [flatted](https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted)